# GAE custom Go runtime - internal.flushLog error

Tags: google-app-engine

I have recently changed to use custom Go runtime on GAE, and noticed many errors like this from logs:

```
internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: Call error 3: invalid security ticket: 6c8027dc99b3ed3e
internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: Canceled: (timeout)
```

The server is still running well, but I have no idea about that error, as well as why it happens.

I'm using a custom Go runtime by using `Dockerfile`, and App Engine Release is `1.9.37`.

Any help to clarify the error would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the Go runtime on App Engine Flexible. It tends to happen when a line is logged right before the end of a request/response.

What happens is that when the line is logged it is actually put in a list of log lines to be batched together and sent to the application server as an RPC at periodic intervals. The security ticket is canceled at the end of a request/response which sometimes can happen before the log lines have been flushed. It's harmless, except that you may lose a log line or two. :\

We're actively working on fixing it.